# classification for some groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, permutation-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group. Suppose that  $G$ acts on a set, say $X$, transitively such that for every $x\in X$, $G_x^g=G_x$ or $G_x^g\cap G_x=\{1\}$. Could you please tell me if there is a classification for such groups?

Comment: can you share why you hope for such classification?

Comment: Any group $G$ acting regularly on $X$ satisfies that condition, and so does every Frobenius group. But there are other examples too, such as any action in which $|G_x|$ is prime.

Comment: Equivalently you want to classify pairs $H\le G$ of finite groups such that $gHg^{-1}\cap H=\{1\}$ for every $g$ not in the normalizer of $H$. Of course it won't be a "classification" stricto sensu, since it should imply a classification of all finite groups (case $H=\{1\}$).